# find encryption algorithm from known input and output

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hash, decode

I have some inputs and outputs of a encryption function and i'm trying to find algorithm of it:

> input:hello
>
> output:eee5ab79be1ca8033fc790603b4d308c3c0a4e38
>
> input:test
>
> output:ebf3c7fb5cecf8ca04ca79dd0bbaa6e42120ffec
>
> input:tennis
>
> output:97e6335558d16337a5e712a3525a3766ab7a3454
>
> input:a
>
> output:0c57bfdc2835cdf0fab05fe08d37ffc5373f1ba8
>
> input:b
>
> output:67482459148ba04c2f12e83cdd18cbfe343978ee
>
> input:c
>
> output:380050d0dbf8293d16b7b4837d84abf4ae6b6d83
>
> input:d
>
> output:d0eae9775bac581b174dc4eaf0f6cc6cd284ad61
>
> input:e
>
> output:00626906c39804e9f441800c629900fd706002f8
>
> input:f
>
> output:7d6ae6cf3aa98f05bace0abc355474810f37c83d
>
> input:0
>
> output:324df299bcf4760d1523cb63ef5c4b2d1d4d371b
>
> input:1
>
> output:4a35df90d96cf1ed7aa008e99d1637b941d29605
>
> input:2
>
> output:2629ecf6a43d69aa06f7dfd5eabdba318d23132d
>
> input:3
>
> output:90225564ae81006f3747fb90d51dab4bac26fbac
>
> input:4
>
> output:3100cc28c4ef0f79e2d29c77a265aef1b2d0e70a
>
> input:5
>
> output:325fbdc73b2e874c287471e315949dc972846434
>
> input:6
>
> output:7d1bad0d82c2b62cfa0719f45acc50732579c206
>
> input:7
>
> output:89dd853798aea657f9ce236b248993b1f5c7bf55
>
> input:8
>
> output:83038f49e7954004aeafd2073b0c0c5a91d1ae7a
>
> input:9
>
> output:ab8fcf8532ed3c0367d6e5fa7230e4317296d6e4

outputs are hexadecimal and fixed length(40 characters)

inputs are unicode characters

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Without additional information, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking isn't possible, because we would need to guess both the encryption algorithm and the encryption key

In addition, it appears that the algorithm in question has a 160-bit block size (which is why the output is a fixed 160 bits - presumably if it were given 161 bits of input then its output would be 320 bits), but I am not aware of any encryption algorithm with a 160-bit block size - block sizes are typically a power of 2 (e.g. 128 bits or 256 bits).  Maybe it's an encryption algorithm with a 128 bit block size plus a 32 bit checksum, but that's just complicating an already impossible task.